# indexOf second argument in Scala

Tags: scala

I want to understand what does second argument in `indexOf` in Scala mean for Strings?

```
object Playground extends App {
    val g: String = "Check out the big brains on Brad!"
    println(g.indexOf("o",7));
}
```

The above program returns: `25` which is something I am not able to understand why?

It is actually the index of last `o` but how is it related to 7? Is it like the second argument `n` returns the index of the occurence of nth character and if `n` exceeds with the number of occurences then it returns the index of last present element?

But if that's the case then this doesn't make sense:

```
object Playground extends App {
    val g: String = "Check out the big brains on Brad!"
    (1 to 7).foreach(i => println(s"$i th Occurence = ${g.indexOf("o",i)} "))
}
```

which outputs:

```
1 th Occurence = 6 
2 th Occurence = 6 
3 th Occurence = 6 
4 th Occurence = 6 
5 th Occurence = 6 
6 th Occurence = 6 
7 th Occurence = 25
```

Source: https://www.scala-exercises.org/std_lib/infix_prefix_and_postfix_operators

Comment: It is the same as https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int,%20int). It just starts the serach at the `n`th index. So, when you say `7`, it starts the search at index `7`... so the first `o` (starting search at `7`) is found at index `25`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Scala String documentation, the second parameter is the index to start searching from:

```
def indexOf(elem: Char, from: Int): Int

Finds index of first occurrence of some value in this string after or at some start index.

elem : the element value to search for.
from : the start index
returns : the index >= from of the first element of this string that is equal (as determined by ==) to elem, or -1, if none exists.
```

Thus, in your case, when you specify 7, it means that you will look for the index of the first character "o" which is located at index 7 or **after** . And indeed, in your String you have two "o", one at index 6, one at index 25.

Comment: Ah I see... Now it completely makes sense. Thanks

Comment: @ShivamSahil No problem, you're welcome

Answer (score 1):

[`indexOf(int ch, int fromIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int,int)) looks for the character in the string from the specified index (`fromIndex`). This means it starts looking at 7th position.

Comment: You mean it starts looking from 7th position right?

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Going forward you need to learn to read the [official docs: indexOf](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.15/scala/collection/GenSeqLike.html#indexOf(elem:A,from:Int):Int):

```scala
def indexOf(elem: A, from: Int): Int
[use case] Finds index of first occurrence of some value in this general sequence after or at some start index.

Note: may not terminate for infinite-sized collections.

elem
the element value to search for.

from
the start index

returns
the index >= from of the first element of this general sequence that is equal (as determined by ==) to elem, or -1, if none exists.
```

I personally like to use Intellij to jump into the source code with `CMD + B`.

No matter how you take it: in your development flow you'll frequently access the manual\docs of the lib or lang you're using.